# How to create sessions in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, session-cookies

In Node.js / MongoDB I want to create an easy session and give it to another page so I can know if a user is logged in or not. I want to know if he/she can access the page or not. How can I do this?

How do I set a session and how do I get the value to check if I have to redirect the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Express.js session](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

It's also worth taking a look at [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org) which makes implementing authentication in Node.js really easy.

Express.js session example:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

// Make sure this is defined before any of your routes
// that make use of the session.
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = 1;
  res.end('User 1 is logged in, please go to the /discussion page.');
});

app.get('/discussion', function(req, res) {
  var sess = req.session;
  if (typeof sess.user === 'undefined') {
     res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<p>user: ' + sess.user + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>');
    res.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how you put the userID in a session and access it on another page. If I use this code, it always tells me that sess.user is undefined.

Comment: Ok, the setting works, but on another page I do this to check if it's set but that won't work. router.get('/', function(req, res){
    app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
                  var sess = session;
  if (sess.user) {
    console.log("yesssss");
  } else {
      console.log("IT isn't working");
  }
});

Comment: I've updated default values in example to remove the deprecation warnings.

Comment: I notice you put the `app.use( session(...) );` in the `/` route.  It should be defined before any of your routes. and especially not inside one of your routes, as shown in the example in the answer.

Comment: Oh ok but I need to access it in another router (/discussion) instead of the file where I create the session.

Comment: It doesn't matter in what file you access as long as the `app.use(session(...))` is used before those two (or more) routes and both routes are defined in the same express app.

Comment: I improved the example, thanks for accepting the answer.