# How to create a node.js session with express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using nodejs and mongodb, the problem is that my express session doesn't work

Frontend code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#signin", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/conectare",
      data: {username: $(".username").val(), password: $(".password").val()},
      success: function(res){
          atentionare(res);  // this is a function that displays a message on the screen
          load_signin_options();  // this is a function that appends more buttons on my navbar
       }
    })
  });
```

and my server code:

```
app.post('/conectare', function(req,res ){
  var user = req.body.username; 
  var pass = req.body.password;

  MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err,db){
    var dbc=db.db("mydb");
    dbc.collection('user').find({username: {$eq: user}}).toArray(function (err, result){
      let len= result.length;
      if( len == 0 ){
        res.send("User does not exist");
      }
      else{
        var a = result[0];
        if(pass===a.password){
          res.send("successfully connected");
          req.session.username = user;
          console.log("parola e buna");
        }
        else{
          res.send("Incorrect password");
        }
        
      }
    });
    db.close();
  });
});
```

this is my session, i also installed express-session

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 0 },
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

i tryed to follow this post [How to create sessions in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726876/how-to-create-sessions-in-node-js)
but and i found out that my session doesnt work, but i don;t understand how to make it work

Comment: You are setting the session after sending the response, when the password matches. Try altering their order.

Answer (score 0):

You set your cookie to maxAge = 0, meaning you're never creating the cookie needed to hold the sessionId.

Change to:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 3600 },// one hour
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: thanks so much, I changed it to one hour, it works now , but when i redirect to another route, the session isn't setted anymore (and i dont destroy the session)

Comment: The problem was that I set the session after res.send() function. It always must be setted before res.send()